# Rotate smart tv screen

Tags: settings, screen, smart-tv

I'd like to use a smart tv box for a kiosk application. Problem is, my client wants the screen to be in vertical mode.

Is there a way to rotate the display to be 1080 x 1920 instead of 1920 x 1080 and rotated 90º?

I'm looking into a box with Android 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be supported by the ROM. Screen orientation change in Android uses support from the graphics driver, the system UI, and the framework that apps use. Either choose a device that has this feature already (ask the vendor if you're not sure), or you'll have to use a custom ROM to achieve this. Since Android STBs are still quite a minority feature, it might be hard to find a custom ROM for your device, and/or hard to get help making your own.

Comment: Do you think this might work? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate

Comment: @Pier It could do, as long as rotation is still enabled in the ROM. But then lots of reviews on the app are complaining that it doesn't work even on devices that can already rotate the screen.

Comment: After some research it turns out the functionality is included in the ROM.